How can I add custom data to an Angular route?
I am declaring my routes typically like this:
{
   path: 'datasel/:datasel',
   component: aComponent,
   resolve: { model: AWATranslationLoaderResolver },
   data: { resolvedata: 'Assets', reuse: true },
}

Is it possible to add some writable data to a route? My idea is to modify that data in aComponent so the reuse strategy would know about some important events happening in the component.
Something like this would be nice to have in component:
    this.router.events.subscribe(ev => {
        if (ev instanceof ActivationEnd &&
            Object.is(ev?.snapshot?.component, aComponent)) {
            ev.snapshot.customData.inportantEvent = true;
        }
    });

and then read that data in the custom reuse class:
shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log(route.customData.importantEvent);
    return !!this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)];
}


Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Just use event bus for that or store, not routing.

If you would like to pass some complex data, you probably need to use a service for this purpose.
As a quick and universal solution, you can write a service which is provided in root, with set and get methods. The set method will set any data to store, so previous page can set a payload. the get method will return the data (if it was set on previous page) and after returning set null to the store. So the next page can get data once. Any next attempt to get data will return null. It will help you to pass any data between pages, during the app routing.
Example of a basic implementation of the service:
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class RoutePayloadService {
  private _store: any = null;

  set(data: any) {
    this._store = data
  }

  get<T>(): T {
    const buff = this._store;
    this._store = null;
    return buff as T;
  }
}


Yes, that definitely works. I will use it for my router solution. I will inject that bus service into my router extension. And also into specific services. So, the bus service will deliver data to specific routes as I am showing in my question.

you can use navigationExtras.status

The router have a method getCurrentNavigations
This return a Navigation object, inside you have "extras.state" that it's an object that you can pass when navigate
 <li [routerLink]="['/details']" [state]="{selectedProduct: product}">

or
  this.router.navigate(['/details'], {status:{selectedProduct: product} });

Then you can get it in your component using:
   selectedProduct = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?
                          .extras?.state?.['selectedProduct'];


Here is my navigation command: this.route.navigate(['/details'],
{ relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' }); This command does not take 3 parameters.

Also, in the component can I change extras?.state?.['selectedProduct'] and read the new value in my shouldAttach method?
